# CUDA Thrust reduce_by_key using less memory

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am trying to reduce the memory required to compute reduce_by_key for my use case. I have a relatively small number of unique keys (around 100-150) compared to the number of values (around 16 million). The reduce by key [example](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#gad5623f203f9b3fdcab72481c3913f0e0) shows that the device_vectors allocated to contain the result is of the same size as that of the inputs. Is it always necessary to do so? Is it possible to only allocate as much memory as necessary to contain the correct output?

Comment: It should be possible to limit the size of your output vectors to be equal to or greater than the maximum number of keys.  Have you tried it?  Don't forget that key sequences must be *adjacent* like keys.  For example, the following sequence: `0   1   0   1` represents *four* "unique" keys.  In the general case, where you don't know how many keys are present, then the worst case is that the output vectors are the same size as the input vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output size of reduction depends on input data, and this value is not typically known before reduction. However, depending on your problem, sometimes you know this size.

Reasonable implementations would require only at least *number of key spans* elements for the output. And `thrust::reduce_by_key` [seems to be included in this list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/thrust-users/dW2BlCYGfA8/9cjijHLJFhoJ).

---

### Examples:

#### Non-sorted (common case)

Output size is hard to predict

```
keys        2   2   2   3   3   2   1
values      1   1   1   1   1   1   1
           |----------|------|----|---|
                    4 spans

reduced         3       2       1   1
```

---

#### Sorted (best case)

Output size is equal to number of unique keys

```
keys        1   2   2   2   2   3   3
values      1   1   1   1   1   1   1
           |--|---------------|------|
                    3 spans

reduced     1           4         2
```

---

#### Interleaved, no adjacent keys repeated (worst case)

Output size is equal to input size

```
keys        1   2   3   1   2   3   1
values      1   1   1   1   1   1   1
           |--|---|---|---|---|---|--|
                    7 spans

reduced     1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

---

Another thing, is that if you don't need keys to be output, you could discard them with `thrust::discard_iterator` and save some extra space, as described [here](https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1discard__iterator.html).